# CSS style is gone on the homepage in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css

I wondered if it's because the homepage's size is big?

I only see my stylesheet working on pages other than the homepage.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give us a link to your website so we can see?

Comment: Do you have a lot of other stylesheets on the home page? IE has a limit of about 31 stylesheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use F12 to bring up the dev console in IE8 and explore the CSS rendering that way. Should be able to track down the exact issue that way.